# Vertically split variable-sized div using CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to divide an auto-scaling `div` into two vertically using two other `div`'s. What I have so far:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='left'>some stuff</div>
  <div id='right'>more stuff</div>
</div>
```

with

```
#frame {
  position: static;
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  /* more positioning stuff */
}
#left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
#right {
  position: static;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

This seems to work OK, except if the contents of `#right` are higher than those of `#left`. In this case, part of the contents of left are invisible. How can I make sure that the height of the left div is also taken into account when the needed height of `#wrapper` is calculated?

**UPDATE**

In the mean time, I've also tried to make both #left and #right static, but then the two dives are not displayed side by side anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the contents of #right are higher than those of #left"?

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen: suppose, for instance, that #right contains one line of text, and #left contains an image of, say, 200px high.

Comment: @Martijn - Ahhh, I see... are you targeting IE6?

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen: not specifically. Of course, I'd prefer an IE6-compatible solution, but IE6 compatibility is not required.

Comment: @Martijn - I assume `#frame` should have been `#wrapper`?

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen: yup, my bad.

Comment: ... changing the positioning to `static` would do that as `static` is the default positioning and `<div>` is a block level element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#wrapper {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}
#right {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

If left needs a background color or background image you'll want to give that background image to the wrapper instead.

This *won't* work in IE6 and may give you trouble in 7 & 8 if you don't use an XHTML doctype...

Comment: Sorry, this does not work: the contents of #left disappear since #wrapper is too small.

Comment: Vertically: #wrapper is not high enough

Comment: Shouldn't happen unless other CSS rules are affecting it.